# How to create a table with a headline centered and columns centered?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I use the following code to create a table with a centered headline.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Headline centered} \\
  \hline
  Column1 & Column2 which should be centered
\end{tabularx}
```

Now I would like to center the second column, too. But the `tabularx` package needs at least one column to be `X` and this column will not be centered.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 7):

Use `l>{\centering\arraybackslash}X`  as your tabular preamble.

---

In addition, something odd about your question struck me, you say `tabularx` needs an X column, which sort of implied that *you* don't need that?

You only need to use `tabularx` if you *need* X columns, that is multi-line entries that break to a width depending on other columns.

If your two columns are of the same type and both need single line entries do not use `tabularx` at all. Use

```
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@\extracolsep{\fill}}c}
```

`tabular*` is vastly more efficient than `tabularx` and does not require any package.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `tabular*` environment. :-)

Comment: @Mico I _always_ suggest people don't use my packages. Packages without users are much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first solution works well. The second one, with the `tabular*` environment, did not center the second column. Maybe I missed something. The reason I used `tabularx` with the `X` column was to fix the first column in the width and let the second column have the rest of the space. But as I am not into deep with tables too much, my attempt may not be the optimal one. :)

Comment: @JohnThreepwood Then have a look at `tabu`

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l|X}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Headline centered} \\
  \hline
  Column1 & Column2 which should be centered
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the package [tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabu):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=3pt % For better spacing

\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {X[L]|X[C]}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Headline centered} \\
  \hline
  Column1 & Column2 which should be centered
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the second column to take remaining space, change the `X[L]` to an `l` (the letter, not the digit).

```
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {X[L]|X[C]}
```

[image]